# Obtain Value from MS Access Checkbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access database in which I store some data, and that database has 13 tables plus a reference one.

I want to make a form where there are several checkboxes and a button. Each chekbox represents a table, and every table selected will be joined inside a query writen in VBA, associated with the button click.

I've already made the same thing in Excel, and it works perfectly, so the only problem here is that I don't know how to access the checkbox value and use an `IF` condition to get the correct SQL string.

To make it clear, here I have a `IF` statement for one of the checkboxes in Excel:

```vb
If Range("B8").Value = True Then

    CTODStrc = ", CTODTYPE, CTOD.TEMPERATURE, VALIDITY,  DELTAR, DELTAL"
    CTODStr = " JOIN CTOD ON REF.ID = CTOD.REF_ID"
    JoinStr = JoinStr & CTODStr
    Columns = Columns & CTODStrc

End If

SQLStr = RefStr & JoinStr 'Query sentence
```

The `SQLStr` is the query text, and it has a prior "select" string which is added.

In Excel, the cell `B8` was associated with the checkbox, but in Access I have to make this condition using a checkbox thats in the form - how can I do it?

I've tried `Me.CbName.Value`, but it says the command is not supported.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checked state of a checkbox is given by the `Value` property of the checkbox control. This property may be `0` (unchecked), `-1` (checked), or `Null` for a block-filled triple state checkbox.

Since the `Value` property is the default property for a checkbox, and assuming you are not using a triple state checkbox, you should be able to use simply:

```vb
If CBName Then
    ' Do stuff
End If
```

Comment: Does not work. It says the object does not support the method.

Comment: Oh, I've noticed now that I used the legend name. Sorry, It's working now. TY.